# Server commands (or equivalent) in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I have a server up and running in my digitaldomain droplet.
in my server code, I have a function called `userCount();` which simply returns the number fo connected users.

I do not want to `console.log` the number of users on my server, each time someone is connected. This just creates a mess. Instead, I would like to be able to run this command whenever I need to see the "current user count".

How can I make my server in a way that, I will also be able to input commands to it (from the console) whenever it's needed?

What is the best and/or most optimal way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

How about exporting the relevant function and execute it whenever you feel like it?

**droplet.js**

```
...
function userCount() {
    return 42;
}
...
module.exports = {
    userCount: userCount
}
```

Create a wrapper file:

**wrapper.js**

```
var connected = require('./droplet.js');
console.log(connected.userCount());
```

Execute that file from the command line:

```
> node wrapper
```

If you do not want to create an additional file, use the node interface:

```
> node
console.log(require('./droplet.js').userCount());
```

Comment: That is not a bad solution! Thank you very much!

Comment: I will still wait a bit more for more answers (if there are any) - if not this is already a solution for me.